# Understanding the chords of "Paradise" by Daniel Caesar?

Tags: chord-progressions, analysis

The song is based on this 4-chord loop:

Abmaj7-Db9-Gmin7-Gbmaj7

I've liked this song for a while and its chords have always mystified me. Why does this progression work? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the bass (root) movement, the progression is a variation of a basic ii-V-I, with a tritone substitution added to the V; so, ii-V-♭ii-I.

But what really makes the progression work is the "melody" the voicings produce, particularly the common tones. The top voice is G-F-F-F, which provides continuity for the ear as the chords change.

Comment: I thought tts needed a 3 and b7 to be swapped over. Gm7 = G Bb D F, Db9 = Db F Ab Cb Eb. What have I missed?

Comment: @Tim You missed that I'm only referencing the root movement, not the complete chord. Particularly in jazz, this is a common technique: use a ii-V-type root movement, but with non-standard chord qualities.

Comment: Thanks, I find I use the 3/b7 a lot, but never used root tts on its own (knowingly...).

Comment: I'm a little surprised that you chose Gb as the most likely key center. I would have guessed Eb, like analogous to IV iv iii biii (ii V I). In particular, for a ii-V-I in the key of Gb, one would expect Abm7 or Ab7 rather than Abmaj7, no? But that's just how I hear it, anyway.

Comment: @user45266 As I mentioned to Tim, I'm only referring to the root movement, not the chord qualities.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since this is a 4-chord loop, I'll try a different perspective:

## A Chord Loop Theory approach

This is going to be an answer based mostly off of Patricia Taxxon's video on the subject in which she proposes an interesting way of looking at 4-chord loop progressions that involves breaking down the loop into individual progressions. The goal of this answer is to see if we can gain any more insight into why the progression works the way it does, as well as coming up with some explanations for some observations. For reference, here it is (it's a bit long):

---

### Step 1

The first step is to draw out our loop diagram, shown here:
[image: Step 1]

As we can see, the exact shape isn't so important so long as we understand that we are proceeding clockwise. The other important thing to remember is that as we look at the unit chord sequences, the last chord will also lead into the first chord, thus why we have a shape that represents a looping path rather than a straight line.

### Step 2

The next step is to assign each individual two-chord sequence some functional labels:

[image: Step 2]

Now, this is one of the hardest steps to get used to. *These aren't typical RNA symbols;* rather, I've isolated each unit sequence of chords and tried to give that its own analysis. Consequently, *the same chord need not have the same symbol in both of its progressions!* Note also that it is important to attempt to assign one of the two chords as the tonic wherever possible. Try to take me at my word for the analysis here - it takes a bit of practice to override the urge to try and label everything in a single key.

- **Abmaj7 Db9**, which I decided was a **I-IV** progression. Now, in the context of the entire loop, some might hear this in other ways, for example as the backdoor IV-bVII in Eb major. However, the idea is to look at those two chords as a simple progression involving a tonic somewhere. Ab is the I chord, and Db is its IV chord. We can ignore the major 7th and the dominant 9th bits for the RNA symbols.
- **Db9 Gm7**, which is a tough one. I-#iv and bV-i are both a bit convoluted, and because they aren't easily-understood progressions, it would be hard to use that label as a way to find insight.

Instead, let's look at some other interpretations of the Db9 chord. It contains an F half-diminished chord (or Abm6) in its upper structure, and it definitely seems like a possible substitution for Abm6. That would give us the sensible Abm6-Gm7, and then we could say that the Gm7 is analogous to a substitution for I. Now, Abm6-Eb is the kind of label that we really want, where one of the chords is a tonic and the other is something that makes sense in relation to that tonic!

Opinions will vary on the best way to write this in the diagram. I actually made a typo in the image, I meant to put bIIm6-i instead of iim7b5-i. I wrote it this way to force one of the chords to be a tonic, although this is not necessary and there are better options. It could also be written as the more abstract form iv-I, but the best way to do it is probably **iv-iii** in recognition of the fact that the minor plagal progression is very easy to understand on the principle of tension and release; clearly, the iii is being resolved to in a sort of stand-in for the I chord. So if it helps to understand, pretend I wrote it as **iv-iii** instead. As we will see, the *exact* RNA is not nearly so important as framing the resolution pattern will be.

- **Gm7 Gbmaj7** is a pretty common progression, so I tagged it as bii-I. In terms of substitutions, we could look at it with the lens of a tritone substitution sub(V)-I if you like, but that's not really necessary. *Note that I rejected the broader analysis ii-bii, since I'm looking for a label that reflects a tension relative to a release rather than an absolute description of the most common functional pattern they form.*
- Finally, **Gbmaj7 Abmaj7** rounds out the loop. I decided to call this a bVII-I progression. Although it's arguable that this could be I-II or maybe IV-V (ignoring extensions), I decided on putting the tonic chord label on the antecedent chord because to me it felt like the progression arrives at the Ab rather than leaving the home of Gb.

### Step 3

The second step was the most difficult because it involves a lot of subjective analysis using unfamiliar frameworks. This last step isn't nearly as hard as the last step was, since it simply takes the results of the previous step and gives them one of two abstract descriptions. *Each of the four progressions gets either the descriptor "Departure" or "Resolution"* (sometimes "Arrival" for consistent theming)*.*

[image: Step 3]

I can go over this pretty quickly since it's just based off of what I did in the previous step:  I-IV is a departure progression for certain. iv-iii is a minor plagal progression; clearly, resolution. Even using the other different RNA labels I suggested, it's apparent because the I chord is in the antecedent position (the second of the two chord symbols). bii-I is also a resolution - this is why it's helpful to have one of the two chords be written up as "I" or "i": it makes it very easy to tell whether it's a departure or a resolution. And last but not least, bVII-I is a resolution as well, which I actually kind of alluded to in advance in step 2. If you heard it more strongly as I-II, then you would have to label this as a departure instead in step 3.

## Okay, so what's the point?

While my having presented a single YouTube video as documentation for the above process should probably give anyone concern, I will say that this process actually does help solve some mysteries of the inner workings of chord loops.

For one, it acts as a nice sensible **check for multitonicity**; in some cases, it will work out that for one section of the loop, all the chords will be relative to one key, and in another, they will all relate to another. In this particular loop, we can back out again to examine the second step as a whole to check that. Since we don't really have places where the tonic chords line up (for example, IV-I followed by I-V), it's a bit harder to see the bitonicity in this loop. My thought would be that there are the two weakened centers of Eb major and Ab major, since it seems like the top of the diamond fits Ab as its secondary tonic but somewhere around the bottom it starts to head back towards the Eb primary tonal center that it never quite reaches. *Tonal centers are a lot more nebulous in this type of analysis; the shared nature of two or more weak key centers is something one must accept in order to understand the new concept of bitonicity in chord loops.*

It also provides explanations for certain aspects of how the loop feels; for example, **loop balance**: some loops feel "balanced" while others do not. This particular loop progression to me doesn't feel so balanced, and the diagram in step 3 agrees with that observation since it shows the loop departing, then resolving 3 times before departing at the beginning again. A more "balanced" loop structure might have a departure, then arrival, departure, arrival. That would demonstrate a bit of symmetry that sets up a smaller cycle within the loop, perhaps making it feel a bit more balanced. A classic example of a balanced progression is the infamous "4 chords of pop" loop, as Taxxon notes in the video.

The other reason I like this approach is it makes for a great **compositional tool**. In fact, Taxxon's video actually uses the Chord Loop Theory diagrams to write a loop for a song twice in the video, and it seems to me to have worked perfectly while simultaneously allowing for unlimited complexity. This process eliminates a lot of the guesswork that often goes into creating good loop progressions, particularly if one wishes to stray from the beaten path of I, V, vi, and IV.

**There aren't many tools out there for dissecting the inner workings of pop music**, with many theory resources being somewhat dismissive of the genre as "simple diatonic loops" and reading them purely linearly. This method, by contrast, goes into depth on understanding the mechanisms at play in a loop progression of any arbitrary complexity. It does have some faults (I'll admit it's not the easiest to learn, and it mostly produces subjective results), and in truth, some pop music simply is better explained with functional harmony. But overall, I think this is a good angle to get used to exploring, especially as 4-chord loops continue to rise in popularity and functional harmony continues to do an incomplete job of explaining contemporary music.